# how big a message ok to send to akka Actor?

Tags: scala, akka

I'm new to akka and I'm trying to use it similarly to the Executor framework to fire off some tasks asynchronously as such:

```
override def receive: Receive = {
    case msg: (Int, ListMap[Double,Double], ListMap[Double,Double]) => processHour(msg._1, msg._2, msg._3)
    case msg: String => println("You sent me a String: " + msg)
    case _ => unhandled() 
}
```

My questions would be:

1. How can I get rid of the compiler warning 
   *"non-variable type argument Int in type pattern (Int, scala.collection.immutable.ListMap[Double,Double], scala.collection.immutable.ListMap[Double,Double]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure"* 
   on the below? I would understand ListMap type erasure, but the compiler seems to complain about the Int..
2. My message (payload) is pretty big (each ListMap has some tens of thousands of raws). The processing consists of displaying the Maps in a plot and computing a sort 'distance' between the two of them.
   Is there a preferred alternative to sending this as a message to gain more from parallelism? I'm thinking along the lines of storing the data outside the actor scope..

Comment: I suggest you add information about the kind of computations you are doing with your large data. E.g. Is each piece of data processable independently or not, is it partitionnable (we can build sub list of independant data) ? Is it all inter-dependant ? As a rule of thumb, do not store data out of actor messages. Akka is a share-nothing mdoel. If you start sharing state outside of your actors, you start fighting the framework, and that will bite you in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning is very common working with pattern matching. The compiler alerts that these types only exist at compile time so it wont differentiate between ListMap[Double,Double] and ListMap[Any, Any]. There are some workarounds using TypeTags. I would give an opportunity to Akka Typed to create a more expressive protocol. An example in how to migrate from classical version to Typed version is detailed here https://www.bbva.com/en/akka-actors-evolution-type-safe-distributed-computations/. For processing big datasets like in your case I´d use Spark.

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't send `String`s and tuples with `Int`s and `List`s. Define a proper protocol with case classes you can pattern-match on.
2. Depends on your definition of "ok". You could try to tweak `maximum-frame-size` (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038115/akka-net-sending-huge-messages-maximum-frame-size)), but then you would soon have to also tweak all kinds of heartbeat-timeouts, because your actors would become increasingly unresponsive, and at some point parts of your system would begin to declare other parts of your system for dead and quarantine each other. With [artery](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/remoting-artery.html?language=scala) this should no longer be a problem.